# Can we measure the one-way speed of anything at all?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, velocity, measurements, one-way-speed-of-light

I know the one-way speed of light question has been [exhausted](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bspeed-of-light%5D+%22one+way%22), and I'm sorry for the naive question, but I would like to understand one thing. Can we measure the one-way speed of anything at all? If we "truly" can, why can't we synchronize that thing and an emission of light from one place to another to compare their speeds? For instance, and for simplicity sake assume 2 cars pass a point at exactly the same time and we know one car is going 60 mph and we do not know the speed of the other car. We could set up a clock 60 miles away, knowing that the car going 60 will take one hour to get there. Then,by using only one clock and by checking the difference in arrival times, we could calculate the second car's speed. Why can't we do something similar with light and another medium. Even if it needed to be sent from some space shuttle to the ISS, it seems like with modern equipment, we should be able to get some decent approximation of the one way speed.

Comment: The speed light is always the same and it’s already been measured.

Comment: @gs if you read more carefully the question, it is not about the one-way speed of light. Therefore, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Bill That's the two-way speed of light. The one-way speed depends on the clock synchronisation convention that you choose. Of course, it's sensible to choose the Einstein synchronisation convention because that makes the one-way speeds equal to each other and to the two-way speed.

Comment: @PM2Ring I guess the question says the speed of anything. But if you’re talking light it’s always the same speed, so I don’t get this one way speed and two way speed, Isn’t light always the same speed? If not how do you explain that?

Comment: "we know one car is going 60 mph" -> 26.8 m/s in what frame of reference? Relative to "the point where the two cars pass"? Is that point stationary? When it is, then in what frame of reference is it stationary? I am asking these rhetorical questions, because a lot of confusions in kinematics originate from the misconception that there could be such a thing as an universal frame of reference.

Comment: @Bill Normally in relativity, we use the round-trip speed of light, and the Einstein clock synchronisation convention. However, ever since Veritasium made a video on the topic, we've had a steady stream of questions about the one-way speed, and the oddities associated with it when you *don't* use the Einstein convention. So we now have a lot of info here about this formerly obscure topic. ;)

Comment: (cont) John D. Norton discusses the one-way speed of light on his [The Conventionality of Simultaneity](https://sites.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/significance_conv_sim/index.html) site. In particular, see the diagrams on the *Reichenbach's ε* page.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks, I’ll catch up

Comment: @Dee Xen, in the near future, I'm going to formulate a different (and hopefully unique) question about measuring the one-way speed of light, as I'm also not 100% convinced that it can't be done.

Comment: Define "speed"--including the terms your definition uses. Then where are you stuck defining or applying? And don't use any undefined terms in phrasing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say no. One of the most fascinating things in physics is time dilation. The speed of light is always the same but the speed of time varies. Not only may A and B be in different time frames as illustrated by others but also at different rates of time change. One way to visualize this is here on earth. It is scientifically theorized that the center of earth is 2 1/2 years younger than the surface of the earth due to time dilation. so first of all which is the correct time? Now if you could send a light to the center of the earth and reflect it back to the surface you begin to see the problem. Even though the speed of light would be the same weather it’s traveling there or traveling back, the actual time and the speed of time would be completely different at both ends.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Because someone didn't understand it. Few people realize that time is so... malleable. And they get grumpy when it interferes with their own pet theories.

Answer (score 16):

> Can we measure the one-way speed of anything at all?

No, there is nothing unique to light in that respect. To measure a one-way speed of anything requires that you allow it to travel over a known distance with a start and stop time measured at the beginning and end of the known distance. Doing so requires that the start and stop clocks must be synchronized. Different clock synchronization conventions will produce different one way speeds. Since any valid synchronization convention can be used, the one way speed simply reflects your choice of convention.

Comment: Doppler effect can be used to measure the speed of galaxies without ever needing for the galaxy to turn back, nor light to go back and forth.

Comment: Although galaxy redshift isn't the best example (for technical reasons), Mauricio brings up an interesting point. How does doppler shift factor in to this? Would this make you reconsider your answer?

Comment: Of course, it should be noted that calculating the velocity from Doppler shift is _model dependent._ How you calculate the velocity based on observed Doppler shift _depends on what model you use_ (e.g. classical mech has a certain formula for Doppler shift, but standard SR uses a different formula, and I assume SR with modified one-way speed(s) of light would result in a different formula). I think that last example might nullify the Doppler method, because you still need a way to decide which formula is the "right one," but that ends up...

Comment: ...requiring you to decide between standard SR vs modified SR, which is a matter of convention. Hence how you calculate velocity based on Doppler shift ends up being a convention as well (out of a class of possible formulas).

Comment: @Mauricio and MaximalIdeal when you change your synchronization convention you also change the formulas for time dilation, length contraction, Doppler shift, aberration, and other effects. There is no way to avoid this issue. This is examined in depth by Reichenbach, who proved there is no way to experimentally detect a synchronization convention.

Comment: While this is true in an absolute sense you should at least mention that for speeds that are neglible relative to the speed of light, the differences in one-way speeds will also be neglible.

Comment: There is something unique to light (well, unique not to light, but massless particles), namely, the time it takes to travel is (with units in which c=1) equal to the distance it travels. For ordinary objects, distance is much less than travel time, so we can synchronize clocks by simply looking at what time we see, without having to worry about how much to adjust the clock by how long it took between the clock reaching a particular time and us seeing it reach that time.

Comment: @quarague not all authors require such limits to the admissible synchronization conventions, so that is not something that I think needs mentioning here, and if I were to mention it then I probably would take the opposite stance

Comment: @Accumulation regarding your proposed synchronization convention, that actually makes my point since one way speeds using your convention will be different than one way speeds using Einstein’s convention

Comment: @Acccumulation That depends on how much of an assumptions you are making on the fact the speeds of the light didn't change two and fro on its outward or back directions. That or the interaction with matter in unforeseen matters or the introduction of subtle but ever present GR effects which would in, the presence of matter distributions, force the light to have a speed be dependent on the gravitational potential (. . . that or take longer than expected before you then average it at the end).

Answer (score 5):

In practice, yes. How much the time coordinate in a "reasonable" anisotropic coordinate system ("reasonable" meaning things like "things don't arrive before they leave") changes over a certain distance, compared to an isotropic coordinate system, can't be more than the spatial separation divided by c. In other words, suppose your car travels 100 feet per second (about 68 mph), or about one light nanosecond per second. That is, for every second in an isotropic coordinate system, its position in that coordinate system changes by one billionth of a light-second. Then an anisotropic coordinate system could say that it actually took (1+1/billion) seconds to travel that distance, or that it took (1-1/billion) seconds.

So we can't measure the *exact* one-way speed, but we can measure it precisely enough as to not make a difference for most practical purposes. (You're not going to get out of a speeding ticket by arguing that there's an anisotropic coordinate system in which you were going 30 mph rather than 60 mph. I mean, that wouldn't work even if there were some such coordinate system, but there isn't one anyway.)

But from a theoretical point of view, the exact one-way speed does depend on the coordinate system, even for a car. The difference between light and a car is that while, for a car, distance/c is miniscule compared to the time it takes to travel that distance, for light it is not. Light travels one light second per second in isotropic coordinate systems, so the time that it takes to travel one light second in an anisotropic coordinate system can vary from 1+1 seconds (giving a speed of c/2) to 1-1 (giving a speed of infinity). And if you try to measure the speed of light by using the speed of a car, the math is going to be such that that miniscule difference between isotropic and anisotropic speeds is actually going to matter.

Like a lot of things in relativity (time dilation, length contraction, etc.), uncertainty in one-way speeds technically exist at any non-zero speed, but in practice it can be ignored for most purposes unless the speed is a significant fraction of c.

Comment: Does this beg the question though? If you assume that the time dilation is the same in both ways, then haven't you have assumed that the speed of light is the same both ways?

Comment: Good insights. Now you say that "we can measure it precisely enough as to not make a difference for most practical purposes" but if it ranges between $\frac c2$ and $\infty$ then we can't measure it precisely at all. So I think what you mean is that for most practical purposes, we don't need to measure it at all since we can synchronize clocks precisely enough using the two-way speed, correct? Also, when you say "there isn't one anyway", are you claiming to know that the one-way speed is isotropic?

Comment: @user400188 How is my answer dependent on time dilation being the same both ways?

Comment: @GumbyTheGreen "but if it ranges between c2 and ∞ then we can't measure it precisely at all." Put in distance per time term, that sounds like a lot. But put in terms of time uncertainty, it's tiny. As my answer says, the uncertainty over a distance of 100 feet is 2 billionth of a second. "Also, when you say "there isn't one anyway", are you claiming to know that the one-way speed is isotropic?" No, I'm saying that even with an anisotropic coordinate system, as long as it preserves temporal ordering, a velocity of 60 mph in the isotropic coordinate system will not be 30 mph in the anisotropic.

Comment: In other words, when I said "there isn't one anyway", "one" doesn't refer to an anisotropic coordinate system in general, it refer to an anisotropic coordinate system that would make an apparent velocity of 60 mph be 30 mph instead. I'm certainly not claiming that the one-way speed is isotropic; I don't think that "one-way speed" refers to anything physical (rather it's merely a property of the coordinate system), and existing is somewhat of a prerequisite of being isotropic.

Comment: But existing is also a prerequisite for being measured, so it seems like a mistake to use the word "measure" there. Maybe you could say "So we can't measure the one-way speed, but we know that it's always fast enough to not make a difference for most practical purposes"? On your last point: How can it be that the one-way speed isn't physical? If you and I are standing in front of each other and you shine a light into my eye, isn't there a definite time coordinate for the arrival of the light relative to its emission within our reference frame (apart from whether we mortals can determine it)?

Answer (score 0):

Measure the length of a finite segment of train track. Start your chronometer when you see the train enter the segment, stop it when it left the segment. If the train was travelling at constant speed you can determine it by calculating length/time.

The reason why this does not work with the one-way speed of light is because light is the thing that you want to measure.

A more sophisticated version is to use Doppler shift, if an ambulance with its sirens on (and you know the frequency of the siren), you can determine its speed by noticing the shift in sound frequency.

As other comments suggest, of course all these measurements and formulas depend on your convention on the one-way speed of light to establish space-time reference frames. Given a convention you can measure the one-way speed of anything that does not travel at the speed of light.

Comment: But it does work because the speed of light is always the same. You just need distance and time. There’s no reason to measure the speed of light, it has already been done many times.

Comment: This requires the start and stop chronometers to be synchronized. Different synchronization conventions will produce different results

Comment: "*Start your chronometer **when you see** the train enter the segment*". Which already puts the event some unspecified time in the past. Ditto for observing the end of the run. Are the two delays the same? Can you ***prove*** they are the same? It is really not that trivial at all!

Comment: @PcMan if one choose to be at the vertex of a regular triangle the last remark you made should be fixed, isn't it?

Comment: @Dale you can use light to synchronize it and fix a reference frame. Are you saying that because we measure the two-way speed of light we cannot measure the train one-way speed?

Comment: Are we assuming that the one-way speed of light is chosen and fixed here? Any convention will do, just that it needs to be explicitly mentioned that we fix that _first_ for this to work. Essentially, this gives a method to determine the one-way speed of something, _assuming_ a one-way speed of light has been chosen. If that is what you're presenting then I think this works.

Comment: Also, as I pointed out in a comment of another answer. Your choice of the Doppler shift formula will _depend_ on the framework you are working in, namely your choice of one-way speed of light. But again, if we agree on a one-way speed of light convention, then we'll agree on the Doppler shift formula.

Comment: @MaximalIdeal got it. You need a convention to establish special relativity and establish reference frames.

Comment: @Alchimista when you are using light to measure timing, and the very thing you want to test is whether light moves at the same speed in all directions....no. Even in real word, and if you assume lightspeed is constant.... Is **time** moving at constant speed along the track of the observed, and along your line-of-sight? If any of the points is moving relative to you, no. If any of the points are in a deeper gravity well (even a few mm of altitude!!).. no...  See how it becomes very complex, very quickly? you can get close, but not exact.

Answer (score 0):

You are aware of this issue of the [conventionality of simultaneity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-convensimul/) or the definitions there in of what the actual one-way speed of light is. That we can define different values for it, making it anisotropic, but in a manner that gives rise to all the same observations that the Special Theory of Relativity ends up covering. The issue is much more deeper than just the one-way speed of light and this conventionality could be applied to all of known physics.

Einstein had actually considered such a general conventionality that went beyond light and he discussed this in a [speech he gave](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol7-trans/224). A paper discussing this and making its own conclusions on the matter about his perspective is given [here](https://www.redalyc.org/pdf/3397/339751454003.pdf).

To make a claim about the speed of an object requires a measure of time (counting periodic occurrences) and a measure of the distance it travels. The problem in most situations is that the assumptions regarding the constancy of its speed in the outgoing then the coming back parts of its journey are assumptions that heavily depend on what our dynamics are and our spacetime structure. You could assume some background spacetime structure and some assumption about the dynamics of objects leading to certain somewhat unobservable conclusions (inferred results). You could, however, change our spacetime structure and change the way objects/particles/fields interact with each other leading to similar observable results but different unobservables. Such as the inferred speed of the object at any point along its trajectory or the distance it *really* traveled.

So it may be the case that the speed of many objects, even ordinary ones, may be fairly conventional. Dependent on our arbitrary assumptions regarding spacetime structure and dynamical interactions.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Derek Muller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derek_Muller) from **Veritasium**, no:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTn6Ewhb27k&ab_channel=Veritasium

At this point in time, we are measuring the 'average' speed of the roundtrip of light. This is due to the problem of needing two points in space to measure speed:

Speed = Distance/Time

So you would need to send off a beam of light from Point A and simultaneously tell Point B that you've started recording. This would need to happen at a speed faster than what we know as light-speed. Which is impossible.

Comment: I think you should reread the question more carefully. Based off of his wording, it's likely he's aware of the video you posted. The veritasium video about the inability to measure the one-way speed **of light.** What he is asking about is whether we can measure the one-way speed **of other non-light objects.** OP is asking a different question than the one you're answering.

Comment: @MaximalIdeal But you propose to measure these other distances by using.... light. If you have not verified the impartiality of the tool, how can you trust what you measure *using* that same tool?